# How can ternary search be applied for the SPOJ challenge - KOPC12A

Tags: algorithm, ternary-search

I was trying to solve the **KOPC12A** problem in SPOJ.

Link to problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/KOPC12A/

**Problem in brief:**

> Given n buildings, each of different height(number of bricks), with
>   each building having a cost for adding or removing a brick, find the
>   minimum cost to make all the buildings have the same height.

After trying to solve this problem, though in vain, I came across a solution that used **ternary search**, after sorting the input based on their heights.

I was not able to understand how the cost for equalizing the heights of the buildings becomes unimodal(because ternary search can only be applied on unimodal functions)

This stumped me and I was not able to proceed much further.

Any insights on this is much appreciated.

Thanks-

Comment: convince yourself that this is a convex problem and if you plot a graph of cost vs height it will be a parabola type graph( not exactly sharp turns and same value etc can there as it is for integer points). Thus you can apply ternary search to find the global minima

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [sasha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437292/sasha)'s comment, we can define the (strong) unimodality of a function `f` as the condition

```
for all x < y < z, f(y) < max(f(x), f(z))
```

and the (strong) convexity of a function `f` as the condition

```
                          z - y        y - x
for all x < y < z, f(y) < ----- f(x) + ----- f(z).
                          z - x        z - x
```

Let the heights of the buildings be `h1, ..., hn` and the unit alteration costs be `c1, ..., cn`. The cost `f(h')` to make all buildings height `h'` is

```
sum i in {1, ..., n} of ci |h' - hi|.
```

Now here is a sequence of propositions, each with a fairly simple proof, leading via induction to the conclusion that `f` is unimodal.

1. The function `g` where `g(x) = |x|` is convex.
2. For all constants `h`, for all convex functions `g1`, the function `g2` where `g2(x) = g1(x - h)` is convex.
3. For all constants `c > 0`, for all convex functions `g1`, the function `g2` where `g2(x) = c g1(x)` is convex.
4. For all convex functions `g1` and `g2`, the function `g3` where `g3(x) = g1(x) + g2(x)` is convex.
5. All convex functions are unimodal.

Comment: such a nice explanation :) +1 , one thing that attracts me to this forum , the way experienced users answer a question.